# How do I add "Everyone" to "Share with" menu?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

In order to share things in my place, I have to go into "Specific people..." and choose Everyone. Is there a way to just put "Everyone" in the right click menu? Homegroup is not an option, since I'm the only Windows computer.

The images below are to the right click menu (first) and the advanced sharing window (second) just to make my question clearer.

[image]

---

[image]